install nfcpy on anaconda
When I try to install nfcpy on anaconda, I get the following:
(base) C:\WINDOWS\system32>conda install nfcpy
Channels:
 - defaults
 - conda-forge
Platform: win-64
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - nfcpy

Current channels:

  - defaults
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.

When I check anaconda.org, I get the following:

There were no items found for this search

The package clearly exists, so how do I install it on conda without using pip?

There were no items found for this search - if it is not available as a conda package, you can a) create one and create a private conda channel b) install it using pip, as recommended in the official docs of the package https://nfcpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/get-started.html

Or even better, create a conda-forge feedstock for it so everyone can benefit from the package!
